# Java - REGEX construction

Tags: java, regex

I've been reading the Java docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) but am having trouble achieving what I want to do. I want to check if the data my user has entered into a text area only contains letters A to Z and ( and ). I'm trying to make an if-statement return false if it doesn't match.

I have tried to do this, but it seems to just accept anything when I try so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us your regex. How else could we tell you where you are going wrong?

Comment: If 1 of the answers satisfies you, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Why would I forget to accept it @MartínCanaval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a regular expression you are looking for then i **think** this does what you need.

```
(?i)[A-Z()]+
```

**EDIT** (corrected based on comments from @dbaupp and @tchrist)

If you want to include numbers you can modify it like this:

```
(?i)[A-Z0-9()]+
```

and with some punctuation ... say (.!,)

```
(?i)[A-Z0-9.!,()]+
```

Comment: What does the '+' on the end do?

Comment: the '+' means 1 or more of whatever is being matched. so the empty string is **not** allowed in Robbie's answer. using `*` will allow the empty string

Comment: it tells it to match 1 or more of the preceeding token

Comment: The `+` is a quantifier (in this case), specifying "at least one occurrence, but no maximum ocurrences (e.g, no limit to the number of occurrences)".

Comment: So, if I wanted to include numbers and other punctuation how would I do this? I take it you put a \ before punctuation you wish to add?

Comment: Would this be correct? [aA-zZ,0-9\.]+ For dots, numbers and letters? On @Hristo's link it seems to work!

Comment: i've updated my answer to include info - you would need to escape the ',' in yours `\,`

Comment: This URL is also very helpful:  [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  By and large, java's regex classes use Perl5 regex syntax.

Comment: @Robbie, thanks top answer! Out of interest, why do you not need the comma? And would this format be correct: String REGEX = "[aA-zZ0-9\.\!\,\(\)]+";

Comment: Is `aA-zZ` the correct expression? Shouldn't it be `A-Za-z` (or just `a-z` with a case-insensitive flag)? (`aA-zZ` is likely to appear to work, by fluke, since the range includes all characters between `A` and `z` in ASCII.)

Comment: you don't need to separate items in the `[]` it's just a sequence of characters that you want it to match. That format would not be correct because you need to escape the parentheses `()`. I use this site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - it has a handy reference list on the right panel with descriptions of what all the characters/operators do.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but when I use String REGEX = "[aA-zZ0-9\.\!\,()]+"; - I get the error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @Robbie, so just so I know what you're talking about, how would you correct String REGEX = "[aA-zZ0-9\.\!\,()]+"; so it actually working in Java?

Comment: @dbaupp Yes, you are absolutely correct. I have updated my answer. I had a mind block or something there with that one.

Comment: @Niles just put slashes infront of the parentheses `[aA-zZ0-9\.\!\,\(\)]+`

Comment: @Robbie Thanks but I'm sorry, I don't really know what you're referring to, currently this is what I have and I have errors with it: String REGEX = "[aA-zZ0-9\.\!\,\(\)]+";

Comment: What are you backslashing all those things in the character class? That’s meaningless.

Comment: @tchrist what would you suggest?

Comment: @Robbie `[a-zA-Z()]+` is plenty. Of course, you should really be using `[\pL()]`, but that’s a different matter.

Comment: Well, the solutions given by tchrist and Robbie worked for me so thank you.

Comment: @tchrist you're right, i thought certain chars had to be escaped, but was wrong. I'll updated the answer. (i'll have to go look up `[\pL()]` )

Answer (score 0):

try this one here

```
String userString = userInput.toString();

if(userString.matches("([A-Z]*(and))*")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match multi-line string from text area, you can use `Pattern.MUTLILINE`. Here's a fully working example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Mkt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc\nD(Ef\n\nxX)x\nqqq\n";
    //String s = "abc\nD(E1f\n\nxX)x\nqqq\n";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\A([a-zA-Z()\\n]+)\\Z", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()) {
      String g1 = m.group(1);
      System.out.println("Found: " + g1);
    } else {
      System.out.println("The text does not match.");
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ javac Mkt.java && java Mkt
Found: abc
D(Ef

xX)x
qqq
```

If you uncomment the second string, it will not match due to having a number `1` in it.